# SVG as background image in IE with zoom

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I have SVG used as background image:

```
<div class="buble"></div>
```

and CSS:

```
.buble
{
  background-image: url(https://beta.creasoft.cz/Images/buble-small.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

When displayed in IE 11 and zoomed (set zoom to 105% or more), it looks broken:

[image]

Works fine in Chrome.
Is there any way how to fix it?

https://codepen.io/raptor/pen/WZoYBB

Answer (score 1):

**IE11** doesn't support the scaling of SVG images when the `viewBox`, `width` and `height` attributes are explicitly specified. In your case, you're giving the image and `width` and `height` of `48px`, which IE11 won't want to scale properly.

To fix it, you can just use a container. The first thing you'll need to do is build the container to house your SVG.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="buble"></div>
</div>
```

Now you'll want to define your container, and add `width: 100%` to the `.buble` div, or SVG.

```
#container {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
.buble {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://beta.creasoft.cz/Images/buble-small-test.svg');
}
```

You may need to also make sure the `height` and `width` are removed from the actual SVG file itself, if it contains it. You can checkout [this GitHub repo](https://gist.github.com/larrybotha/7881691) for more info about SVG's + IE.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work. tried to create simple wrapper with fixed size, but backgroud image is not displayed inside. Inline svg is just the same as referenced one. https://codepen.io/raptor/pen/xXRMMv/

Comment: If you can use inline (or even `img`) SVG instead of background, that's way easier. See this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzVwGB).

Comment: This "buble" is used on multiple places in whole web and it is just "background" image. There is text over it etc. So I want to use it using CSS only. I don't want to inline it multiple times. I understand now that scaling is problem in IE, but still there must be some workaround. For example this one works better. Only 105% is broken. https://codepen.io/raptor/pen/YrpgJE

Comment: If you need it to be a `background-image`, try [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wroZzL). I don't have IE to test the zoom.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to fix, it doesn't work when user uses zoom in browser :-)

Comment: I understand what you're trying to fix, I'm just saying I don't have IE to test any of the code, so I'm just making educated guesses. The last [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wroZzL) didn't work? The `background-image` is set to 100% `width` & `height`, so I'd assume it'd work in IE when zooming since it's not using explicit values anymore.

Comment: Same result as in original question. Image is "cut" on the right and on the bottom side when zoom is 105%.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you access the file directly in IE, what is its size? Have you tried removing the `viewBox`, `width` and `height` from the actual `.svg` file? The file you're referencing [here](https://beta.creasoft.cz/Images/buble-small-test.svg) has the `viewBox` defined as 72 x 72 still. You need to open the SVG in an image editor to just remove the code which is present in the opening `<svg>` tag.

Comment: viewBox is required to set "default size" if I understand correctly. Everything other is scaled based on viewBox values.

Comment: `viewBox` isn’t necessary. With this method, you’re setting the “default size” with the `#container` because the SVG is set to 100% of that container. When `viewBox` is set in the SVG code, IE 11 will only use those values or other explicitly set values in CSS, but no percentages. All dimensions need to be removed from the SVG file itself, and any CSS that directly targets the SVG tag, except for `width: 100%`. You can test removing the `viewBox` in the CodePen that has the inline SVG code.